# Error when test my app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in all of coding and I am busy building an app in Swift. I am making a button which when it is pressed, it should go to the next page which is a page which has a camera functionality of AVCam. The first page opens just fine, and when I press the button to go to the camera view page the app crashes.

The button code to go to the camera view page is as follows:

```
@IBAction func goToApp(sender : AnyObject) {
    let AVCamViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCamViewController") as UIImagePickerController
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCamViewController, animated: true)
}
```

When I try it on my phone, the error after the app has crashed it as follows:

```
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x1001f32c4:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
0x1001f32c8:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
0x1001f32cc:  add    fp, sp, #16
0x1001f32d0:  mov    x20, x1
0x1001f32d4:  mov    x19, x0
0x1001f32d8:  ldrb   w8, [x20, #32]
0x1001f32dc:  tbz    w8, #0, 0x2c
0x1001f32e0:  tbnz   w19, #0, 0x4c
0x1001f32e4:  cmp    x19, #1
0x1001f32e8:  b.lt   0x44
0x1001f32ec:  mov    x0, x19
0x1001f32f0:  bl     0x10f24
0x1001f32f4:  cmp    x0, x20
0x1001f32f8:  b.eq   0x20
0x1001f32fc:  ldr    x0, [x0, #8]
0x1001f3300:  cbnz   x0, 0xfffffffffffffff4
0x1001f3304:  b      0x28
0x1001f3308:  mov    x0, x19
0x1001f330c:  mov    x1, x20
0x1001f3310:  bl     0xc1ec
0x1001f3314:  mov    x19, x0
0x1001f3318:  cbz    x19, 0x14
0x1001f331c:  mov    x0, x19
0x1001f3320:  ldp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
0x1001f3324:  ldp    x20, x19, [sp], #32
0x1001f3328:  ret    
0x1001f332c:  brk    #1
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1001f332c)
```

If I run it on the simulator the error is as follows:

```
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x1001c2f90:  pushq  %rbp
0x1001c2f91:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x1001c2f94:  pushq  %r14
0x1001c2f96:  pushq  %rbx
0x1001c2f97:  movq   %rsi, %rbx
0x1001c2f9a:  movq   %rdi, %r14
0x1001c2f9d:  testb  $0x1, 0x20(%rbx)
0x1001c2fa1:  je     0x1001c2fd0               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 64
0x1001c2fa3:  testb  $0x1, %r14b
0x1001c2fa7:  jne    0x1001c2feb               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 91
0x1001c2fa9:  testq  %r14, %r14
0x1001c2fac:  jle    0x1001c2feb               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 91
0x1001c2fae:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x1001c2fb1:  callq  0x1001d5194               ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
0x1001c2fb6:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x1001c2fc0:  cmpq   %rbx, %rax
0x1001c2fc3:  je     0x1001c2fde               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 78
0x1001c2fc5:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x1001c2fc9:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x1001c2fcc:  jne    0x1001c2fc0               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x1001c2fce:  jmp    0x1001c2feb               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 91
0x1001c2fd0:  movq   %r14, %rdi
0x1001c2fd3:  movq   %rbx, %rsi
0x1001c2fd6:  callq  0x1001cfa90               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClass
0x1001c2fdb:  movq   %rax, %r14
0x1001c2fde:  testq  %r14, %r14
0x1001c2fe1:  je     0x1001c2feb               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 91
0x1001c2fe3:  movq   %r14, %rax
0x1001c2fe6:  popq   %rbx
0x1001c2fe7:  popq   %r14
0x1001c2fe9:  popq   %rbp
0x1001c2fea:  retq   
0x1001c2feb:  leaq   0x16067(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x1001c2ff2:  movq   %rax, 0x77c67(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1001c2ff9:  int3   
0x1001c2ffa:  nopw   (%rax,%rax)
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Any idea where the error could be?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the controller is not of the expected type, causing a cast error. Try breaking up the first line as

```
@IBAction func goToApp(sender : AnyObject) {
    let controller = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCamViewController")
    let AVCamViewController = controller as? UIImagePickerController
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCamViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

That should make it easier to see if it manages to instantiate the controller by that identifier at all, and if so, whether it is of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `AVCamViewController` extends `UIImagePickerController`?

*(Hint: It doesn't, it extends UIViewController: [AVCamViewController.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Listings/AVCam_AVCamViewController_h.html))*

When you're using the `as` keyword to cast in Swift, you have to be sure that your variable is of the type you're casting it to. Try changing this:

```
let AVCamViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCamViewController") as UIImagePickerController
self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCamViewController, animated: true)
```

To this:

```
if let AVCamViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCamViewController") as? UIImagePickerController {
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCamViewController, animated: true)
} else {
    NSLog("Our AVCamViewController is not a UIImagePickerController")
}
```

Note I made two changes to your `let` statement:

1. Changed `let` to `if let` (also adding braces)
2. Changed `as` to `as?`, making the cast safer (it will fail if the cast cannot succeed)

So, that's the **safe** way do perform the cast. But since we already know it's not a `UIImagePickerController` but rather a `UIViewController`, you should be able to do this instead without issue:

```
if let AVCamViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AVCamViewController") as? UIViewController {
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(AVCamViewController, animated: true)
} else {
    NSLog("Our AVCamViewController is not a UIViewController")
}
```

Comment: Craig, when correcting it to what you suggested, I got the "Our AVCamViewController is not a UIImagePickerController" result. Do you know the AVCamViewController extends to? I have tried AVCamViewController and AVCamViewController.h and even AVCamViewController.m but with all of them I get error in the code. UIImagePickerController was the only one that I didn't get an error with, so that I could at least run the app. Could you or anyone tell me what it extends to or maybe another camera feature I could use in my app?

Comment: Why not try `UIViewController`? If you look at the header file, that's what it extends.